# meaning of 'ziehen' in a sentence

Tags: meaning

What does the verbe ziehen here mean?

> Die Schwedische Akademie zieht die Konsequenzen aus dem
>   Mißbrauchskandal, und das ist gut so.

To me it sounds like

> The Swedish Academy decided to go with the consequences from the rape scandal, and that is good that way.

Here, who judges "that is good that way"?
Is it the writer? or the Swedish Academy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*aus (+ D)  Konsequenzen ziehen* is a fixed *Nomen-Verb Verbindung*, it has to be interpreted as a whole, and means, e.g. according to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Konsequenz)

> aus etwas Negativem lernen und daraus die Folgerungen ziehen, sich dementsprechend verhalten

Or, a translation is [*to take appropriate action / steps*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=konsequenzen%20ziehen&=DEEN&=).

> Here, who judges "that is good that way"? 
>   Is it the writer? or the Swedish Academy?

The writer.

Comment: https://www.dict.cc/?s=die+Konsequenzen+ziehen+aus

Comment: ok, I asked how to interpret German and you explain it in German. : D. The google translation interprets the Duden explanation "learn from something negative and draw the consequences from it, behave accordingly". Can you elaborate on 'draw' here? Is it 'to go with ~' or 'to let ~ happen' ? It sounds like it to me.

Comment: Did you see the added link to the translation as "take appropriate action" !?

Comment: @ChanKim Actually no.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. ziehen is a verb representing a combination of actions. (learn from a bad case + reach a conclusion + behave accordingly). I think the google translation should have said 'draw a conclusion' instead of 'draw a consequnces'. The `das ist gut so` clearly is what the write says, though.

Comment: @ChanKim that's right. I didn't interpret correctly the question. I've fixed the answer.